# Angular change components and hide component

Tags: angular

I have this page that has 3 components loaded on it. (Picture below)

Now when I click on Component 3, it will be switched to Component 4. When I click on Component 4 it should switch to Component 5 **but also hide / remove component 2**. How can I achieve this ?

[image]

I switch component 3,4 and 5 using route, so the page loads the different component.
I apologize for the title or if this has been answered somewhere.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz for getting better idea what you want to achieve?

Comment: You can achieve this by using ngSwitch that, for every 'step' load a <custom-component></custom-component>

Answer (score 0):

create a boolean in a service can be a solution :

service.ts

```
…
public hideMe: true;
```

component2.ts

```
import { MyService } from '……';
…
constructor (public service: MyService) { }
```

component2.html

```
<div *ngIf="service.hideMe">
  your code…
</div>
```

Now you just need to `service.hideMe = false` whenever you `(click)` on your **component 4**